# How to use colspan and ngFor in Angular material 6 table?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-material-6

I'm using Angular Material to render the table.

[image]

Code:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="type">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Workout type </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let workout"> {{workout.type}} </td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="set1">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight x Reps </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let workoutData"> {{workoutData.workoutSessions[0].sets[0].weight}} x {{workoutData.workoutSessions[0].sets[0].repetitions}} </td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="set2">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight x Reps </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let workoutData"> {{workoutData.workoutSessions[0].sets[1].weight}} x {{workoutData.workoutSessions[0].sets[1].repetitions}} </td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="set3">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight x Reps </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let workoutData"> {{workoutData.workoutSessions[0].sets[2].weight}} x {{workoutData.workoutSessions[0].sets[2].repetitions}} </td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="set4">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight x Reps </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let workoutData"> {{workoutData.workoutSessions[0].sets[3].weight}} x {{workoutData.workoutSessions[0].sets[3].repetitions}} </td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="set5">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight x Reps </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let workoutData"> {{workoutData.workoutSessions[0].sets[4].weight}} x {{workoutData.workoutSessions[0].sets[4].repetitions}} </td>
</ng-container>

<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="workoutTableColumns"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: workoutTableColumns;"></tr>
```

I have 2 questions about this:

1) Is it possible to iterate thru an array using *ngFor in this situation? Now my code looks too messy, want to clean it.

2) Is it possible to use colspan? I didn't find any information that this issue is solved (issue: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5888 ).

So, the main quesion is: Is it better to use Angular material table or regular one in this particular situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no reason why you couldn't do the following:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let set of workoutData.workoutSessions[0].sets; let i = index" [matColumnDef]="'set' + i">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight x Reps </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let set"> {{set.weight}} x {{set.repetitions}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

Most of it is self explanatory, the main change is to change `matColumnDef="setX"` to be `[matColumnDef]="'set' + i"`. By adding the square brackets, it causes the value to get evaluated to a string rather than just read 'as is'.

Comment: what about colspan?

Comment: You cannot use `colspan` with a `MatTable`. If you want to use it then you need to use Material's `CdkTable` as opposed to the `MatTable` which is a fairly different way of writing the table. This gives you a native table and you can use colspan as you would normally. See the following link: https://material.angular.io/cdk/table/overview

Comment: @Simon K disagree, cause for that is angular attrs!

Comment: @Andris `colspan` can be set like any old attribute, sure, but it will not have any effect whatsoever on the `MatTable` as `MatTable` doesn't look at that attribute.

Answer (score 3):

I don't like accepted answer, cause it suggest some workaround. Actually colspan is attr. So you can add colspan using `[attr.colspan]` like `[attr.colspan]="columns.length"`

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="demo">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item" [attr.colspan]="columns.length - 1">...</td>
    </ng-container>
```

Comment: could you provide any example?

Comment: I added example. But there isn't much to write, cause it is just attr.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old question though for your 2nd question, yes you can use colspan in matTable. Here is a sample code for mat-header-cell :-

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="set5">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef colspan="3"> Weight x Reps </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let workoutData"> 
  {{workoutData.workoutSessions[0].sets[4].weight}} x 
 {{workoutData.workoutSessions[0].sets[4].repetitions}} </td>
</ng-container>
```