# Unable to use colspan in angular material table

Tags: angular, typescript, html-table, angular-material, expand

Is it possible to use colspan in angular material table or is there any other way that I can achieve colspan in any other way?

I have tried `[attr.colspan]` but result is not proper. As soon as I added `[attr.colspan]` it applies colspan but moves symbols to a new unknown column.
[image: sample table]

Comment: you can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55701270/how-colspan-and-row-span-added-to-material-table-header-angular-7

Comment: but it all about table header. I want it for other row.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How colSpan and row Span added to material table Header Angular 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55701270/how-colspan-and-row-span-added-to-material-table-header-angular-7)

Comment: no, I don't want it on header. I want colspan on row. It won't help in my scenario.

Comment: @pooja why do you use use colspan here?  why don't you just create a column with Symbol?

Answer (score 2):

You can use  `[attr.colspan]` this is an example

```
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="column">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef [attr.colspan]="3">Column</th>
    </ng-container>
    </table>
```

Comment: I have already try [attr.colspan] but not get proper result. I have added image in my post. Please have a look.

Comment: if you have no proper result it means that something else in your code prevent your rules to be applied, could you please create a stackblitz of your code?

Comment: hi, stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wwg2uj?file=src%2Findex.html.

Comment: I only want 9 postion "Weight" option to be apply for colspan.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `colspan` with material tables. You can hower set the `[matColumnDef]` to define what columns need to be displayed.
 Or `[attr.colspan]` is an attribute you can use on mat-table. Although I haven't tried it myself.

> Column definition for the mat-table. Defines a set of cells available for a table column.

[Angular Material Table API](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api)

If you really want to use colspan you can read [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51035108/how-to-use-colspan-and-ngfor-in-angular-material-6-table) thread where it is explained how you can use colspan with `CdkTable`.